# Parse XML records into multiple tabs (with PHP or jQuery)

Tags: php, jquery, parsing, tabs, xml-parsing

I'm currently working on a website of a DJ and he uses GigaTools for his gigs. 
At the moment I have the GigaTools feed (which is xml) parsed with php and show on the website with a table. But this is only limited to a maximum number (12) of records that is shown, because thats what fits on the website.

This is the script that I'm currently using:

```
      <?php 

    $gigatools = simplexml_load_file('http://gigs.gigatools.com/user/MikeRavelli.xml');
    echo "<table id='gigs_parse'>\n";

    for($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++) {
      $event = $gigatools->event[$i];
      $day=$event->day;
      $month=$event->month;
      $name=$event->name;
      $venue=$event->venue;
      $city=$event->city;
      $country=$event->country;

      if($month == 1){
        $maand = 'JAN';
      } else if($month == 2){
        $maand = 'FEB';
      } else if($month == 3){
        $maand = 'MAR';
      } else if($month == 4){
        $maand = 'APR';
      } else if($month == 5){
        $maand = 'MAY';
      } else if($month == 6){
        $maand = 'JUN';
      } else if($month == 7){
        $maand = 'JUL';
      } else if($month == 8){
        $maand = 'AUG';
      } else if($month == 9){
        $maand = 'SEP';
      } else if($month == 10){
        $maand = 'OCT';
      } else if($month == 11){
        $maand = 'NOV';
      } else if($month == 12){
        $maand = 'DEC';
      }

      echo "<tr class='row'><td class='date'><span>",$day,"</span><br/>",$maand,"</td>\n";
      echo "<td class='party'><a href='",$url,"' target='_blank'>",$name,"</td>\n";
      echo "<td class='location'>",$venue,", ",$city,", ",$country,"</td>\n";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

I want the xml feed to be shown in multiple tabs, so that its possible to show more gigs then 12. For example if there 15 gigs in the feed, I want the first 12 to be on the first tab and the other 3 on the second tab. 
I would like to show as much tabs as needed for the number of gigs that are in the feed. So the number of tabs has to change automatically according to the number of gigs that are in the feed. So I wont get any empty tabs.

I searched for half a day now and I can't find any good solutions on the internet. 
I'm not that good at programming, so I really need a tutorial or a script that I can adjust.

Can someone point me in the right direction with for example a tutorial or help me with a script for this?

Thanks in advance! 
And b.t.w. sorry for my bad english ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [JQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/).

You can find a very easy example [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/default.html). It should be easy to change your script to generate a table like that

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Second</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Third</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
    <p>First tab contents</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Second tab contents</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Third tab contents</p>
</div>
</div>
```

After that you have to add all the js and css required by JQuery UI in the `<head>` of your document:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
<script src="../../jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
<script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.tabs.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../demos.css">
```

Finally, simply call the function that actually creates the tab

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
</script>
```

Comment: I allready looked at that, but the problem with this is that I have to predefine the tabs. 
What I would like is it that the script will automatically create tabs, depending on the number of records that I get from the parse of the xml feed.

Comment: I think it's probably easier to adjust the server-side php script in order to do that.

You know the number of events, so the number of tabs will be ceil(numEvents/12). Now that you know the number of tabs, you have just to repeat your current loop more times.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I adjusted my php script and added the jQuery UI tabs to it. Now i just have to style it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks man! Was searching for a PHP XML Parser for Gigatools...

I'm also new to PHP, but wouldn't it be nicer like this:

```
<?php 

    $feed = 'http://gigs.gigatools.com/user/MikeRavelli2.xml';
    $gigatools = simplexml_load_file($feed)or
          die ("Fehler beim Laden des Feeds: ".$feed."\n");;
    $countgigs = count($gigatools->event);
    echo "<table id='gigs_parse'>\n";
    if ($countgigs > 12) {
        $gigs = 12;
    } else {
        $gigs = $countgigs;
    }

    for($i = 0; $i < $gigs; $i++) {
      $event = $gigatools->event[$i];
      $day=$event->day;
      $month=$event->month;
      $name=$event->name;
      $venue=$event->venue;
      $city=$event->city;
      $country=$event->country;

      if($month == 1){
        $maand = 'JAN';
      } else if($month == 2){
        $maand = 'FEB';
      } else if($month == 3){
        $maand = 'MAR';
      } else if($month == 4){
        $maand = 'APR';
      } else if($month == 5){
        $maand = 'MAY';
      } else if($month == 6){
        $maand = 'JUN';
      } else if($month == 7){
        $maand = 'JUL';
      } else if($month == 8){
        $maand = 'AUG';
      } else if($month == 9){
        $maand = 'SEP';
      } else if($month == 10){
        $maand = 'OCT';
      } else if($month == 11){
        $maand = 'NOV';
      } else if($month == 12){
        $maand = 'DEC';
      }

      echo "<tr class='row'><td class='date'><span>",$day,"</span><br/>",$maand,"</td>\n";
      echo "<td class='party'><a href='",$url,"' target='_blank'>",$name,"</td>\n";
      echo "<td class='location'>",$venue,", ",$city,", ",$country,"</td>\n";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
```